# Can use AVCaptureMoiveFileOutput send stream video to the Network?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I need to send screen video in real-time from Mac to a multicast group,like"239.1.1.110:46110".

I know the AVCaptureMovieFileOutput has a method"startRecordingToOutputFileURL: recordingDelegate:".

I just want to know the parameter of URL can be a multicast group address? Or if is no,what can I do to send the stream video to the multicast group?

Someone said using ffmpeg,but I nothing about that.Could anybody give some sample demo?

Any help is appreciated.Thanks a lat in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this project provided by Apple - [AVFoundationQueuePlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVFoundationQueuePlayer-iOS/Introduction/Intro.html)